# Set startup parameters for MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed vanilla MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I see the following files in /etc/mysql/ (using ls command):

conf.d
debian-start
debian.cnf
my.cnf
my.cnf.fallback
mysql.cnf
mysql.conf.d

my.cnf looks like this:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I have tried adding this to the end of my.cnf:

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=4
transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

I then stop MySQL and try to start it. Starting gives me a error without any info.

Comment: No errors in the logfile at all? What if you run `mysqld` directly from the commandline? Provide concrete reproduction steps including all commands, and the output _verbatim_ (a 22.6k user should know to do this here!)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. I also needed to add an [mysqld] line.

my.cnf now looks like this where the first 2 lines were there originally.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=4
transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

MySQL now starts properly and I have verified that the parameters have been set.